# Why is margin-top off by 2px on a Mac?

Tags: php, css, cross-platform, margins

If you view my website on a PC, the image under the links should fit snugly under the links.

However, if you view it on a Mac, the image is about 2px overlappin the links above it.

Do Mac browsers interpret CSS values differently?  Such as margin-top, which is what I'm using?

Is there an easy solution to this with CSS, or do I need to designate separate CSS values after detecting the platform with PHP?

Comment: what browser are you using on the mac, and what browsers on the PC are you comparing it to? (also please state the browser versions, as this can also have a significant bearing on things too)

Comment: firefox and chrome, I guess.  I'm pretty sure it's all current browsers.  I've tested on Safari and Explorer too.  I really don't think it's a browser issue.  It's a platform issue, and I've seen it before.

Comment: FWIW, I compared the link in Chrome (14.0.835.186) on both OSX and WinXP, and the OSX version has the overlap that @bozdoz mentions. I haven't looked into why this is the case yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display lines up in Mac Chrome if I set `body { font: 12px/20px Verdana; }`, forcing the line height of the nav text. This isn't a fix, it just demonstrates that it's the font size that's breaking your world.

This method of applying design elements to a page is (in my opinion) pretty old-school and fragile. My recommendation would be to break up the background so its components can be tied to individual elements on the page rather than relying on little nudges to line things up. Pretty much everything you're doing could be accomplished with straight CSS, anyway.

Comment: Works!  Thanks.  What does 12px/20px do?  Is that a range?

Comment: the `12px/20px` directive is short-hand for a font size of 12px, and a line-height of 20px.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a reset CSS stylesheet:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Great suggestion.  Thanks. Adam Backstrom had the winning suggestion this time, but I think a reset CSS stylesheet is the way to go generally.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this css file. It will be reset all style. http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Comment: Great suggestion.  Thanks. Adam Backstrom had the winning suggestion this time, but I think a reset CSS stylesheet is the way to go generally.  Thanks.